# AWS EC2 Transitioning From Pay As You Go to Reserved Instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a micro instance of EC2 that I am currently paying for using pay-as-you-go.  I am thinking about transferring this instance to a reserved instance (upfront fee + lower hourly charge).  I read through the documentation [here](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/purchasing-options/reserved-instances/), but am still unclear about a couple of things.

First, will I be able to seamlessley 'transfer' my current pay-as-you-go instance onto the reserved instance platform without having to move my snapshot onto a new server?  Also, does the 'Reserved Instance Type' only refer to the down payment + hourly rate options you have and not have anything to do with the actual performance of the box?  From what I've read, I should choose the 'Heavy Utilization' option since the box will be running a site that is up 24/7.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not have to move your server or make any change when buying a reserved instance. You simply need to select an RI that is the same size and in the same region and availability zone as your current system. Heavy utilization is the best choice for you if your system runs 24/7. If you don't think you'll need it for a full year, consider buying from the marketplace where you may be able to buy in some increment lower than 1 year.

Answer (score 3):

Reserved instances are just a billing feature. All you need to do is create a reservation that matches the parameters of your current instance.

Answer (score 1):

It breaks down like this:

- You just purchase an RI, and if it happens to match a running instance (same Region, Zone and Instance Type), you get a discount when running the instance.
- Multiple RIs will match multiple instances.
- If you're not running a "matching" instance, you don't get a discount.
- The RI type (Heavy/Medium/Light) is just a trade-off on up-front cost vs discount cost. If you're running 24x7, get the heavy, it will save you the most money. If you don't want to invest a lot now, you can get the light and pay a little more, but loose less if you stop your instance.